# Java LocalDateTime.parse takes forever

Tags: java, datetime-format

Following code throws an exception "could not be parsed at index 0".

```
String dateTimeText= "14/06/2017 15:16:23";
String origFormat="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeText, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(origFormat));
```

Note: In actual code, dateTimeText i am reading from a file. I am guessing some how this is getting corrupted. As the above code works, but when I read from the file it doesn't.

Comment: [Works fine for me.](http://ideone.com/4asTKZ) Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I think you need to print. System.out.println(date); cheers

Comment: suppose you try a different method to parse the date. if possible there are lots of examples to do the task. refer [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/)

Comment: If it throws an exception, it wouldn't be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not at the date parse part.

Maybe you should check the file read function or the file format.

The string from file may has some invisible character at beginning.
Like some UTF8 file has BOM. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark